# From C# via CLR book: synchronization by reference and value types

Tags: .net, synchronization

Please, what do you think what output will be appeared in console (kind of trivia):

Sync by reference type:

```
class Program
{
    static int x = 8;
    static object obj = new object();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(f1));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(f1));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(f1));
        Thread t4 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(f1));

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        t3.Start();
        t4.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void f1()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(obj);

        x++;              
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine(x);

        Monitor.Exit(obj);
    }
}
```

Sync by value type:

```
class Program
{
    static int x = 8;
    static int y = 444;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(f1));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(f1));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(f1));
        Thread t4 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(f1));

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        t3.Start();
        t4.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void f1()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(y);

        x++;              
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine(x);

        Monitor.Exit(y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head (you said trivia), I would say that the Monitor.Enter(int) will receive a boxed copy of y, so you'll be locking on four distinct objects instead of one, rendering the lock useless.

Not a good question BTW. You should have asked *why* it isn't working the way you expect.